# Retrieval of Table data in .doc file to .csv programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, csv, ms-word, doc

I am trying to retrieve data from tables in .doc to .csv files programmatically using C#. Due to few conditions, i cannot install Microsoft office on the client machine . Is there any other way to accomplish this as Microsoft PIA wont work without Office being installed.

Comment: If you were using DOCX files, rather than DOC files, you could use the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).
This is a very thin wrapper around the XML format of OOXML files, so is pretty low-level. However, it only works with DOCX files.

Comment: Aspose also produce a product that will do what you want, but it's a few thousand dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) library, which can help you read/write xls, doc, ppt files. It does not have a dependency to Office.

An alternative could be also [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/).